# Can't align <div> in center and can't manage opacity properly

Tags: php, html, css

Please have a look at the image and the code below. I am making simple signup html form. I am trying to keep  in middle of the screen. also I just want to make div background opacity 50% but somehow, text input's and button's opacity is also changed to 50%.
Please help me to find a solution.

Here's a code of a simple signup form.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sign Up</title>
</head>
<body background="back.jpg">
    <form>
        <div style="background-color: rgb(255,255,255); opacity: 0.5; display: inline-table; padding: 20px; border-radius: 25px;">
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your E-Mail here" style="border-radius: 25px; padding: 5px; outline-style: none;"><br><br>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password" style="border-radius: 25px; padding: 5px; outline-style: none;"><br>
            <p style="color: rgb(58,58,58);"><input type="checkbox" name="tnc"> Accept T&C</p>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up" onclick="submit" style="border-radius: 25px; padding: 5px; width: 150px; outline-style: none;">
        </div>  
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

[See Output of the code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WDPS.jpg)

Please explain or answer deeply. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use this color code for the div if you want to make its opacity 50% only`<div style="background-color: rgb(255,255,255,.5); opacity: 0.5; display: inline-table; padding: 20px; border-radius: 25px;">`and then you dont have to use the opacity for the div.

first give some width to your form`form{width:600px;margin:auto; display:block; }`it will makes your form in center.
to give margin from top and bottom give style like this`form{margin:150px auto;}` so it will also give margin from top-bottom.

Comment: this thing solved my opacity issue. thanks. but alignment issue is still there.

Comment: i will help you with that too please tell in detail what kind of things you need in design?

Comment: and if the opacity problem is solved please accept my answer.

Comment: thanks for your help. your code did almost everything I want. just tell me that if I browse my page in a small screen or extra large screen then it will effect my design or not.

Comment: yeah the form width can create some problem in small scree but i also have some tips for that issue too.Where we use width:600px; use this form{max-width:600px; width:100%;} so it will make your form responsive for small screen.for any other concern please ask.

Answer (score 0):

Try this your code will be run

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sign Up</title>
</head>
<body background="back.jpg">
    <form>
          <div style="background-color: rgba(255,255,255, .5); display: table; padding: 20px; border-radius: 25px; margin: 0px auto; text-align: center; top: 50%; left:50%; position: absolute; transform: translate(-50%, -50%)">
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your E-Mail here" style="border-radius: 25px; padding: 5px; outline-style: none; background: #fff;"><br><br>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password" style="border-radius: 25px; padding: 5px; outline-style: none;"><br>
            <p style="color: rgb(58,58,58);"><input type="checkbox" name="tnc"> Accept T&C</p>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up" onclick="submit" style="border-radius: 25px; padding: 5px; width: 150px; outline-style: none;">
        </div>  
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

show code bellow:

```css
body {
    text-align: center;
}
form {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sign Up</title>
</head>
<body background="back.jpg">
    <form>
        <div style="background-color: rgb(255,255,255,0.5);display: inline-table; padding: 20px; border-radius: 25px;">
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your E-Mail here" style="border-radius: 25px; padding: 5px; outline-style: none;"><br><br>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password" style="border-radius: 25px; padding: 5px; outline-style: none;"><br>
            <p style="color: rgb(58,58,58);"><input type="checkbox" name="tnc"> Accept T&C</p>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up" onclick="submit" style="border-radius: 25px; padding: 5px; width: 150px; outline-style: none;">
        </div>  
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: tell for for more help

Answer (score 0):

I have prepared a snippet for you, using the display: table(-X) properties:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sign Up</title>
</head>
<body background="back.jpg">

    <div style="display:table; height:calc(100vh - 50px); width:100%;"><!--  Change the "-50px" part to whatever size your navbar is -->
        <div style="display:table-row;">
            <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align:middle; text-align:center;">
                <form style="margin:auto;">
                    <div style="background-color: rgb(255,255,255); opacity: 0.5; padding: 20px; border-radius: 25px;">
                        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your E-Mail here" style="border-radius: 25px; padding: 5px; outline-style: none;"><br><br>
                        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password" style="border-radius: 25px; padding: 5px; outline-style: none;"><br>
                        <p style="color: rgb(58,58,58);"><input type="checkbox" name="tnc"> Accept T&C</p>
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up" onclick="submit" style="border-radius: 25px; padding: 5px; width: 150px; outline-style: none;">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps!